# Loading dynamic links in a jQuery UI Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, hyperlink

I 'm trying to open the links from an RSS feed into a dialog. I am trying the following code which I got from [here](http://www.ashishblog.com/blog/example-of-jquery-ui-dialog-with-dynamically-loading-an-url-with-an-iframe/). The link does not open dialog. Any suggestions what I 'm doing wrong.
thanks

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
              $('a#URLLoad').live('click', function(e) {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  var page = $(this).attr("href")
                  var pagetitle = $(this).attr("title")
                  var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
                    .html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>')
                    .dialog({
                        autoOpen: false,
                        modal: true,
                        height: 625,
                        width: 500,
                        title: pagetitle
                    });
                  $dialog.dialog('open');
              });

          });

    <li class="ui-state-default">
<a class="URLLoad" href="http://feeds.arstechnica.com/~r/arstechnica/index/~3/4UlQiQB2n54/">New Xbox interface brings Windows 8 "Metro" style to the console</a></li>
```

**UPDATE:** http://jsfiddle.net/daxnp/

Comment: [May I suggest a different way to structure that?](http://jsfiddle.net/3E6Vp/). Also, no reason to prevent the autoOpen just to call it directly after creation, it's an unnecessary redundancy.

Comment: its working fine. Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zQdb4/1/

Comment: His jsFiddle works completely fine, and to drive the point home, [here's another fiddle using the method I outlined above.](http://jsfiddle.net/CTqe4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using class not id change your code like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
              $('a.URLLoad').live('click', function(e) {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  var page = $(this).attr("href")
                  var pagetitle = $(this).attr("title")
                  var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
                    .html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>')
                    .dialog({
                        autoOpen: false,
                        modal: true,
                        height: 625,
                        width: 500,
                        title: pagetitle
                    });
                  $dialog.dialog('open');
              });

          });
```

you need to change `$('a#URLLoad')` to `$('a.URLLoad')`

**Update:**

i have updated your fiddle have a look here [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/daxnp/1/)

i think problem is that you have not included reference of jquery UI and css

Comment: that doesnt still load the URL into dialog

Comment: I think the problem is with the references as mentioned ..I get "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog'" when i inspect the element in chrome

Comment: that's what i said you have some conflict in your source try finding that first view source of link provided by you http://www.ashishblog.com/ash/dialogUI.html